# How can i connect to Websocket actioncable on EC2?

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, puma, actioncable

I have tried multiple times to connect to the websocket server made with actionable and deploy on an Amazon EC2.

Unfortunately I encounter this problem over and over again when I go to the page that will allow me to display the messages sent in websocket.

Javascript can't connect to the server and I don't understand why.

I tried to change the nginx configuration several times, as well as changing the incoming EC2 rules without success.

I also changed several times the parameters "config.action_cable.url" and "config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins".

the error show by the navigator is with when i test with client  : "WebSocket connection to 'ws://52.47.133.83:3001/test/cable' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
"

and websocket is disconnected: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused on IOS client.

Nginx.conf

```
upstream app {
 server unix:///home/ubuntu/happer-api2/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}

upstream thin {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

location /{
  root /home/ubuntu/happer-api/public;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;

  if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
    rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
  }
  if (-f $request_filename.html) {
    rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
  }
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    proxy_pass http://thin;
    break;
  }
}

location /test {
    root /home/ubuntu/happer-api2/public;
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    index index.html index.htm;
}

location /cable {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/happer-api2/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}

location ~* ^/assets/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/happer-api2/public;
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do

config.cache_classes = false

config.eager_load = false

config.consider_all_requests_local = true

if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.cache_store = :memory_store
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
  }
else
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.cache_store = :null_store
end

config.active_storage.service = :local

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

config.active_support.deprecation = :log

config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

config.assets.debug = false

config.assets.quiet = true

config.action_cable.url = 'ws://52.47.133.83:3001/test/cable'
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ["http://52.47.133.83"]


config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Comment: No error logs? Response headers?

Answer (score 0):

Your security groups or NACL are blocking access. You see this in the error message.

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

You'll need to open the required ports as AWS security defaults to no accesss.

Comment: thank you for giving me an answer , I have already tried to change the rights of incoming tcp ports with no result .